# Protractor Clicking a Dropdown issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to run protractor and a jquery selector is returning an error. But it works on my chrome when i try it on console?

I am trying to select "TestE2E" from dropdown menu.

This is what I Tried:

```
browser.actions().click($( ".portal-list li a:contains(TestE2E)" )).perform()
```

I have even tried

```
elements(By.css('.portal-list li a:contains(TestE2E)').click()
```

I get this error:

```
    ✗ Go back to experiences page (0.37 secs)
      - InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.portal-list li a:contains(TestE2E)' is not a valid selector.
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.130)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64)
```

How can I fix it? This is my HTML

```
<div>
<ul><li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">TestE2E</a>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't you include an ID into the anchor (e.g `<a id="e2e" href="javascript: void 0;">TestE2E</a>`) and then use it (e.g `browser.actions().click($('#e2e')).perform()`)?

Comment: They are dynamically generated so I can't keep adding ID's for everything. That's not a solution for me :-(

Answer (score 1):

How about this instead?

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.portal-list li a', 'TestE2E').click()
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText